# How can i estimate speed per year based on speed per day?

Tags: statistics, physics

consider the following data:

```
        date        mm/year
2469    2006-10-05  0.3885
2472    2006-10-08  0.4095
2473    2006-10-09  0.4095
2474    2006-10-10  0.4095
2475    2006-10-11  0.3441
2476    2006-10-12  0.3224
2477    2006-10-13  0.3224
2478    2006-10-14  0.3640
2479    2006-10-15  0.2905
2480    2006-10-16  0.0284
2481    2006-10-17  0.0284
2496    2006-11-01  0.0284
2497    2006-11-02  0.0284
2498    2006-11-03  0.0284
2499    2006-11-04  0.2485
```

This is a small sample of my data which covers a period of 2 full years.

These data represent the decreasing speed of the thickness of an object based milimeters per year. Knowing that my object has a base thickness of 5mm, and the thickness loss per day expressed in mm/year, how can i calculate the total thickness loss for a given period of time of say 2 years?

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: What do you mean by "thickness loss per day expressed in mm/year". Does this mean that the measurement for each day is expressed as how much the thickness would decrease over a full year if it decreased by the same amount every day?

Comment: yes, is exactly that

Comment: could it work if i convert the mm/year to mm/day dividing by 365? this would give the mm/day of thickness loss

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take an average of your data points.
Multiply by the number of years you wish to estimate.
This will give you an approximate mm loss over that many years.

E.g. suppose your average was 0.4mm/year and you want to estimate 3 years of loss.

0.4mm/year * 3years = 1.2mm

Comment: Hi Ben, thank you for your answer. I could do that if the mm/year given per day were constant, but they change everyday so i think i could not calculate it that way

Comment: While this is a good general heuristic, it is worth noting that this method of extrapolating will likely be highly inaccurate for the data set given. While we can only see the data given, there appears to exist a steady decrease in the rate of thickness-loss over time. Hence, assuming the the mean thickness-loss-per-day today will be the same in the future is a poor assumption to make.

Comment: i agree with you @Brian

Comment: I completely agree with @Brian. It is always important to be aware of the assumptions of the model you are extrapolating.

Comment: @Miguel2488 To be fully clear, this method _does_ provide a highly appropriate estimate within the domain of the data collected. If you goal is only to find the net change over a period of time, Ben's answer certainly suffices. I feel my initial comment was somewhat ambiguous about this distinction.